# Do I need to add an addon for the built in PostgreSQL rest API?

Tags: postgresql

I have tried using the PostgreSQL rest api. I have followed the documentation but not sure if I need to enable it with an add-on as I am not getting a response from the Rest API. I just get a refused connection.

Here's a link to the API: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/HTTP_API#Querying_a_Database

Thanks :)

Comment: Postgres has no "buil-in" REST API. You obviously didn't see the line "*This page is an early draft **proposal** of an extension to PostgreSQL*" at the top of that page.

Comment: Ah. My bad. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in REST API.  To quote the page you link:

> This page is an **early draft proposal** of an extension to PostgreSQL allowing clients to access the database using HTTP instead of PostgreSQL's proprietary protocol (FEBE).

Comment: Ah. My bad. Thank you for that.